# VB.net SUM :error Index was outside the bounds of the array

Tags: sql, arrays, vb.net, sum

I have a problem with the SQL SUM function

The error I got:

> Index was outside the bounds of the array.

My code:

```
SQLcmd = New SqlCommand("SELECT SUM(CAST(distance AS Numeric(10, 1))) FROM route WHERE id BETWEEN '" & op.departure_id & "'AND '" & op.arrival_id & "'", SQLCon)

Dim r As SqlDataReader = SQLcmd.ExecuteReader

    While r.Read()
        distance = r(3).ToString()
    End While
```

The error is on the `distance = r(3).ToString()`

Comment: Have you tested if there is and element in position 3?

Comment: There is only one field returned by that query. Why did you try to read a field at index 3? You could only use index 0

Comment: Yes.. the position 3 is distance columms

Comment: Can you provide us the entirely code of that function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query selects a single column - `SUM(CAST(distance AS Numeric(10, 1)))`. You should access it with index `0`, not `3`:

```
While r.Read()
    distance = r(0).ToString()
    ' Use distance somehow...
End While
```